# SQL Server: Performance issue: OR statement substitute in WHERE clause

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, query-optimization

I want to `select` only the records from table `Stock` based on the column `PostingDate`.
The `PostingDate` should be after the `InitDate` in another table called `InitClient`. However, there are currently 2 `client`s in both tables (client 1 and client 2), that both have a different `InitDate`.

With the code below I get exactly what I need currently, based on the sample data also included underneath. However, two problems arise, first of all based on millions of records the query is taking way too long (hours). And second of all, it isn't dynamic at all, every time when a new client is included.

A potential option to cover the performance issue would be to write two separate query's, one for Client 1 and one for Client 2 with a `UNION` in between. Unfortunately, this then isn't dynamic enough since multiple clients are possible.

```
    SELECT      
        Material
        ,Stock
        ,Stock.PostingDate
        ,Stock.Client
    FROM Stock
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT InitDate FROM InitClient where Client = 1) C1 ON 1=1
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT InitDate FROM InitClient where Client = 2) C2 ON 1=1  
    WHERE   
        (
            (Stock.Client = 1 AND Stock.PostingDate > C1.InitDate) OR
            (Stock.Client = 2 AND Stock.PostingDate > C2.InitDate)
        )
```

Sample dataset:

```
CREATE TABLE InitClient
(
    Client  varchar(300),
    InitDate    date
);
INSERT INTO InitClient (Client,InitDate)
VALUES
    ('1', '5/1/2021'),
    ('2', '1/31/2021');
SELECT * FROM InitClient

CREATE TABLE Stock 
(
    Material    varchar(300),
    PostingDate varchar(300),
    Stock   varchar(300),
    Client  varchar(300)
);
INSERT INTO Stock (Material,PostingDate,Stock,Client)
VALUES
    ('322', '1/1/2021', '5', '1'),
    ('101', '2/1/2021', '5', '2'),
    ('322', '3/2/2021', '10', '1'),
    ('101', '4/13/2021', '5', '1'),
    ('400', '5/11/2021', '170', '2'),
    ('401', '6/20/2021', '200', '1'),
    ('322', '7/20/2021', '160', '2'),
    ('400', '8/9/2021', '93', '2');
SELECT * FROM Stock
```

Desired result, but then with a substitute for the OR statement to ramp up the performance:

```
| Material | PostingDate | Stock | Client |
|----------|-------------|-------|--------|
| 322      | 1/1/2021    | 5     | 1      |
| 101      | 2/1/2021    | 5     | 2      |
| 322      | 3/2/2021    | 10    | 1      |
| 101      | 4/13/2021   | 5     | 1      |
| 400      | 5/11/2021   | 170   | 2      |
| 401      | 6/20/2021   | 200   | 1      |
| 322      | 7/20/2021   | 160   | 2      |
| 400      | 8/9/2021    | 93    | 2      |
```

Any suggestions if there is an substitute possible in the above code to keep performance, while making it dynamic?

Comment: Why do your sub queries have a `TOP` but no `ORDER BY`? Surely you can't be happy with an arbitrary row being returned each time you run the query (and that arbitrary row can be different **every** time you run said query).

Comment: I agree, it's unnecessary. Though, since there are only two records (1 per client), the result is every time the same in this case. I'll edit it out.

Comment: Then why the `TOP`? If the subquery can *only* return 1 row *without* the `TOP`, then the `TOP` should not be there.

Comment: Exactly, so that's why I removed it, and as you can see, it yields the same results. Thanks for the remark.

Comment: No one but you knows / understands your model as represented by overly simplified DDL. But it seems odd that client 1 has init date of May 1 2021 yet has stock with Jan 1 2021. Equally odd is why you outer join while also refering to the unpreserved tables in the WHERE clause - defeating the outer join . And your joins make no logical sense to me. Without understanding your goal and the decisions you chose in writing this rather strange query it is difficult to suggest anything

Comment: The reason is the following: InitDate is the date when the current Stock situation is calculated over all data in the entire system (over decades). Everything before that date we subtract, everything after that date we add. Because clients have different initialization dates, we need to extract all the Stock info before all initialization dates of different clients. Because all these records need to be OR subtracted OR added. For Client 1 in this case Stock of March '21 need to be subtracted from the initialization stock and Stock for Client 2 in this case needs to be added.

Comment: This is indeed somewhat confusing, it's common to deal with multiple clients or tenants. this is obviously a contrived example but your query is returning the date for each client as a column - what would you do with 100 clients, or 1000?

Comment: A good point and decided to edit that out of the query entirely. Are there maybe some keywords in what direction I could search further to solve at least the dynamic join based on potentially more than 2 clients? Because I have a hard time finding anything related to this problem.

Comment: I consider this question clear. Basically we have a problem and we have a solution which involves subselects and left joins and the solution works, but we need ideas of how we can reach an equivalent solution that is quicker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can optimize this query quite a bit.**

- Firstly, those two `LEFT JOIN`s are basically just semi-joins, because you don't actually return any results from them. So we can turn them into a single `EXISTS`.
- You will also get an implicit conversion to `int`, because `Client` is `varchar` and `1,2` is an `int`. So change that to `'1','2'`, or you could change the column type.
- `PostingDate` is also `varchar`, that should really be `date`

```sql
SELECT      
    s.Material
    ,s.Stock
    ,s.PostingDate
    ,s.Client
FROM Stock s
WHERE s.Client IN ('1','2')
  AND EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM InitClient c
    WHERE s.PostingDate > c.InitDate
      AND c.Client = s.Client
);
```

- Next you want to look at indexing. For this query (not accounting for any other queries being run), you probably want the following indexes (remove the `INCLUDE` for a clustered index)

```sql
InitClient (Client, InitDate)

Stock (Client) INCLUDE (PostingDate, Material, Stock)
```

- It is possible that even with these indexes that you may get a scan on `Stock`, because `IN` functions like an `OR`. This does not always happen, it's worth checking. If so, instead you can rewrite this to use `UNION ALL`

```sql
SELECT      
    s.Material
    ,s.Stock
    ,s.PostingDate
    ,s.Client
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM Stock s
    WHERE s.Client = '1'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT *
    FROM Stock s
    WHERE s.Client = '2'

) s
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM InitClient c
    WHERE s.PostingDate > c.InitDate
      AND c.Client = s.Client
);
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2ffabbaf7b44a298f3309f206310f0a3)

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong in expecting your query to be dynamic. However, in order to make it more performant, you may need to reach a compromise between to conflicting expectations. I will present here a few ways to optimize your query, some of them involves some drastic changes, but eventually it is you or your client who decides how this needs to be improved. Also, some of the improvements might be ineffective, so do not take anything for granted, test everything. Without further ado, let's see the suggestions

## The query

First I would try to change the query a little, maybe something like this could help you

```
SELECT      
    Material
    ,Stock
    ,Stock.PostingDate
    ,C1.InitDate
    ,C2.InitDate
    ,Stock.Client
FROM Stock
LEFT JOIN InitClient C1 ON Client = 1
LEFT JOIN InitClient C2 ON Client = 2
WHERE   
    (
        (Stock.Client = 1 AND Stock.PostingDate > C1.InitDate) OR
        (Stock.Client = 2 AND Stock.PostingDate > C2.InitDate)
    )
```

Sometimes a simple step of getting rid of subselects does the trick

## The indexes

You may want to speed up your process by creating indexes, for example on `Stock.PostingDate`.

## Helper table

You can create a helper table where you store the `Stock` records' relevant data, so you perform the slow query ONCE in a while, maybe once in a week, or each time a new client enters the stage and store the results in the helper table. Once the prerequisite calculation is done, you will be able to query only the helper table with its few records, reaching lightning fast behavior. So, the idea is to execute the slow query rarely, cache/store the results and reuse them instead of calculating it every time.

## A new column

You could create a column in your `Stock` table named `InitDate` and fill that with data for each record periodically. It will take a long while at the first execution, but then you will be able to query only the `Stock` table without joins and subselects.

Comment: I checked the index and it seems to be fine. However, the additionally loading of the records sound like a workaround. Weirdly enough without the OR statement and a UNION, it takes only 1 minute. As soon as I add the OR statement it takes 3 hours and 30 minutes... Still sounds weird to me why the OR statement blows up the time THAT much.

Comment: @titatovenaar I try to understand your comment. What does "I checked the index and it seems to be fine." mean? Do you already have an index? What is the index and why is it fine? "However, the additionally loading of the records sound like a workaround." I did not recall additionally loading records, nor unions. My suggestions, in a nutshell were as follows: 1. Getting rid of subselects, 2. Indexing, 3. Helper table storing the result of the query either via a daily cron job or a trigger being executed when a client is added,

Comment: @titatovenaar 4. A Stock.InitDate column being created and maintained and then you can get rid of the left joins and subselects, so your query will be executed in less than a minute, at least this is pretty safe to assume based on what you described. If there are any further problems that you have, or the solutions are inefficient, please let me know.